# Javascript: Detect checked boxes isn't working with form with only 1 checkbox. Working with 2 or more

Tags: javascript, forms

I have the function below. It gets the values from checked boxes and transfer it to a textbox. It is working... but only if the form has 2 or more checkboxes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendValue()
    {
        var all_values = '';
        boxes = document.DataRequest.itens.length
        
            for (i = 0; i < boxes; i++)
            {
                if (document.DataRequest.itens[i].checked)
                {
                    all_values = all_values + document.DataRequest.itens[i].value + ","
        
                }
            }
    
        window.opener.document.getElementById('emailto').value = all_values;
        self.close();
    }
</script>

<form name="DataRequest">
    <input name="itens" type="checkbox" value="name1">
    <input name="itens" type="checkbox" value="name2">
</form>
```

Am I missing something to make this work with only 1 checkbox?

Comment: Don't give the same name to 2 checkboxes.

Comment: `document.DataRequest.itens` is only Array-like if there are more than one checkbox. Otherwise it returns just the element.

Comment: @Esailija you should write an answer, I think.

Comment: I don't feel like writing the code, you can do it @dystroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is one item. it does not return array

```
  function sendValue()
    {
        var all_values = '';
        boxes = document.DataRequest.itens.length
            if(boxes>1)
            {
            for (i = 0; i < boxes; i++)
            {
                if (document.DataRequest.itens[i].checked)
                {
                    all_values = all_values + document.DataRequest.itens[i].value + ","

                }
            }
            }
           else
             {
              if (document.DataRequest.itens.checked)
                {
                    all_values = document.DataRequest.itens.value 

                }
             }

        window.opener.document.getElementById('emailto').value = all_values;
        self.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to give different names to your inputs :

```
<form name="DataRequest">
    <input name="item1" type="checkbox" value="name1">
    <input name="item2" type="checkbox" value="name2">
</form>
```

Using the same name to your inputs is technically possible in your case but a terrible practice as the name is normally what's identify for a form the different inputs.

Then, to access your inputs, you must use a different syntax. More than one version are possible but you can do this :

```
var boxes = document.forms['DataRequest'].getElementsByTagName('input');
var tokens = [];
for (var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
    if (boxes[i].checked) tokens.push(boxes[i].name+'='+boxes[i].value);
}
var all_values = tokens.join(',');
```

Note that the use of `join` avoids the trailing comma.

Comment: thanks for the code, but I use the same input name to do another check... and in this case i MUST use this way. I really appreciate your helpful time on this.

Answer (score 0):

not sure how much compatibility you need with IE 6 - 8, but if that's not required you can use

```
function serializeChecked() {
   var values = [];
   var checked_boxes = document.querySelectorAll('form[name="DataRequest"] input[checked]');
   for (var i = 0, l = checked_boxes.length; i < l; i++) {
     values.push(checked_boxes[i].getAtrribute('value'))
   }
   return values.join(',');
}


function sendValue() {
  window.opener.document.getElementById('emailto').value = serializeChecked();
}
```

If you do require IE support, use document.DataRequest.getElementsByTagName('input') instead of QSA and iterate through them to collect the values if they have the checked attribute.